# Limiting number of emails to a email recipient in sendgrid

Tags: sendmail, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I am using sendgrid golang api to send emails based on some trigger in my code. I have a requirement where I need to limit the number of emails that can be sent to the particular email address, is it possible to apply such sort of limit at sendgrid side. So no matter how many times my code triggers the email, it will be limited for a particular email address.

Answer (score 0):

No, SendGrid doesn't have that functionality. You'd need to implement that logic on your side.